# How are ECR passport checks enforced in India?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india, ecr

India has a [peculiar system](http://www.immihelp.com/nri/ecnr-emmigration-check-not-required-stamp.html) where non-educated Indian citizens need a special 'emigration check' in order to work in certain countries.

How is this system enforced in practice? Does the airline check for ECR stamps before checking-in passengers? Do border officials check one's passport before leaving the country? And how does it work for Indians departing from bordering countries, such as Nepal?

Comment: NB: I'm not an Indian citizen, just curious how the system works.

Comment: ECR check is required only for Gulf countries, to prevent human trafficking.

Comment: I've heard of this before, but am unclear on what the actual *check* involves. Do you have to pass a literacy test in the language of the country to which you are going? Do they pull you aside to give you the number for an anti-human trafficking hotline, then mark the check as complete? Do you have to submit documents that convince the Protector of Emigrants to approve your emigration?

Comment: Relevant page from the government of India: http://www.mea.gov.in/emigration-clearance-system.htm

Comment: @RobertColumbia that sounds like an excellent separate question!

Comment: @RobertColumbia Not a full answer to your question, but [this document](http://www.indianembassy.org.sa/Content.aspx?ID=783) for Indians going to work in Saudi Arabia (or [this one](http://cds.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/uae.pdf) for the UAE) gives you an idea of what they're looking for. I like how it says to never give up your passport, followed by a statement that employers in Saudi Arabia will keep your passport. I also think Protector-General of Emigrants is a fantastic title.

Comment: Phillipines also has this, where they check if eligible young women travelling alone are actually goong for stated purpose (tourism/work) or for flesh trade. Failure to establish your purpose without any proofs might make you miss your flight. Gulf Countries have system of Exit Permit where you have to get permission from your employer or sponsor to go out of country for any reason. Failure to get this might get you detention, where your sponsor needs to come and pick you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an Indian passport applicant does not fulfil [certain conditions](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/onlineHtml/NonEcrDocuments.html), then the passport has "Emigration Check Required" printed in it.(Note: I can't find a current image of such a print)

India has exit border checks and each passenger's passport and boarding card is checked and stamped by the border agent. From the [Bureau of Immigration](http://boi.gov.in/content/indian-passengers) website (emphasis mine):

> Indian nationals travelling abroad require a valid Indian passport and
>   travel authority for the destination country.
>
> The travel authority is normally in the form of Visa, which is
>   obtained prior to the journey, except in case of countries where "Visa
>   on Arrival" is available.
>
> Indians traveling abroad may also note that some countries insist for
>   certain minimum period of passport validity for allowing entry & for
>   this confirmation should be obtained from the Embassy/travel agent.
>
> **Indians having the Emigration Check Required (ECR) category of
>   passports require POE clearance from Ministry of Overseas Indians
>   Affairs for certain destinations if traveling on Employment Visa.**

The "certain destinations" [are](http://boi.gov.in/content/encrecr):

> United Arab Emirates (UAE), The Kingdom of Saudi Arabia (KSA), Qatar,
>   Oman, Kuwait, Bahrain, Malaysia, Libya, Jordan, Yemen, Sudan,
>   Afghanistan, Indonesia, Syria, Lebanon, Thailand, Iraq (emigration
>   banned).

The ECR check thus is enforced by Bureau of Immigration. A passenger with a passport that has the ECR stamp, and travelling to the specified countries on an employment visa needs to have an "Emigration Clearance" from the Protector of Emigration(PoE). From the (somewhat flaky) website of [PoE Chennai](http://www.poechennai.in/emigration_clearance_system.php) (empahsis mine)

> ‘Emigration clearance (EC) is a kind of legal authorization for
>   ‘emigration’ obtained in the prescribed manner and form from the
>   Protector of Emigrants (POE).  Emigration clearance is issued under
>   provisions of Sec 22(1) of the Emigration Act 1983.  **This
>   authorization is currently issued in the form of a ‘security sticker’
>   duly signed by the POE and gets pasted on the Passport of the emigrant
>   who requires Emigration clearance**

The procedure to obtain such a clearance is given [here](http://www.mea.gov.in/emigration-clearance-system.htm). The applicant needs to submit a few documents (employment contracts and insurance) for getting a clearance.

Thus **ECR check at border is done by checking the passenger's passport/visa** and if the passport has an ECR stamp, then the **"Emigration Clearance" sticker for the destination country**. In case the passenger does not have these, he/she will not be allowed to leave India. [Immihelp](http://www.immihelp.com/nri/ecnr-emmigration-check-not-required-stamp.html) provides more information about "special" one time clearances in exigent circumstances, but I cannot find an official link for the same.

Also note that for any other type of visa for travel to the ECR countries, the emigration clearance is **not** required provided the passenger can show return tickets. [From the Ministry of external affairs website](http://www.mea.gov.in/emigration-abroad-for-emp.htm):

> ECR passport holders going to any of the notified countries (ECR
>   countries) on any visa other than employment visa, are allowed to
>   travel on production of following documents at the Airport:
>
> Valid Passport
>
> Valid visit/residence/study visa etc.
>
> Return Ticket

For your other question

> And how does it work for Indians departing from bordering countries,
>   such as Nepal?

I am not sure. As ECR check is done by Indian border officers, presumably there is little they can do if the passenger departs from Nepal or other neighbouring countries.

Comment: So it seems that the check happens when you leave India to a country (from the above list) and for that country you have an employment visa in your passport. Sounds like if you travel to some other country as a tourist before going to your destination country would be a "workaround"?

Answer (score 3):

If you did not attach 10th class certificate (Matric) while applying for passport, you used to get passport with words printed on second page :" Emigration Clearence Required blah blah blah...." Then you were supposed to go to passport office again (people also used touts with cost about 1000 Rs) to get this paragraph striked, and Passport Officer's signature and stamp saying ECNR on same page.

If you attached educational certificate, then it used to get striked auto on issuance.

If you are going on a work visa to Gulf or few other countries, and has ECR status, border control will notice and will not let you go out of country without ECNR. Immigration officer will make you go back and get the ECNR from passport officer of your area/district. This essentially means you will miss the flight.

Regarding the try to circumvent it, by going to Nepal and flying from there, I believe this is possible, as many people go to Iraq/Syria etc for work (because agents promised them moon and back salaries because of war zone) via Dubai/Nepal. India does not allow people to go to Iraq/Syria for work, so people just say, have visa, for Dubai/Gulf.

Like any other country, you check-in at airline counter, get boarding passess, and need to go through immigration if international flight. There Immigration Officer will check boarding pass, will ask the reason of travel, and might want to see the documents you will use to enter your destination. If the destination is on list, and you are going for work, he will check the ECR/ECNR/POE, and you essentially will not be allowed to cross the border (need to go back to sort it).

Relevant Quote from [Buraeu of Immigration, India](http://boi.gov.in/content/encrecr)

> As per the Emigration Act, 1983, Emigration Check Required (ECR) categories of Indian passport holders, require to obtain "Emigration Clearance" from the office of Protector of Emigrants (POE), Ministry of Overseas Indian Affairs for going to following 18 countries.
>
> United Arab Emirates (UAE), The Kingdom of Saudi Arabia (KSA), Qatar, Oman, Kuwait, Bahrain, Malaysia, Libya, Jordan, Yemen, Sudan, Afghanistan, Indonesia, Syria, Lebanon, Thailand, Iraq (emigration banned).

Some more info from [ImmiHelp](http://www.immihelp.com/nri/ecnr-emmigration-check-not-required-stamp.html)

*this website does not allow me to select text on mobile?*

Source: I co-ordinate between 70+ mixed nationalities employees and Official HR Department for these all visa/travel related processess in a Gulf Country.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question: _How (and where) is this restriction enforced in practice?_

Comment: Yeah but what happens if you rock up to the airport with an ECR passport? And what if you cross into Nepal and then try to fly away?

Comment: @henning Makholm Immigration Officer will check this while you try to board flight, and will not let you pass, essentially making you miss your flight, and go to Delhi Head Office (difficult) or your area Passport Office to get the ECNR Stamp (easy).

Comment: Slightly misleading explanation. _If you are going on a work visa to Gulf or few other countries, and has ECR status, border control will notice and will not let you go out of country without ECNR_. The quoted para explicitly states you need an emigration clearance (which I believe is a separate sticker on your passport) if you have ECR. This is different from needing an ECNR passport to go out as your explanation implies.

Comment: @RedBaron there is no seperate ECNR Passport, the sticker you are referring to might be another one of Ministry of Employment/Emigration. Before 2007 all passports by default were ECR, and we had to get the ECNR Stamp. Example Screenshots http://imgur.com/Qlo8sB8 http://imgur.com/AGFVpjQ

Comment: @DavChana I was referring to your explanation about needing an ECNR to go out of the country. That is not strictly true. If you have an ECR stamp, you need an emigration clearnace (adhesive sticker stamps) from PoE on your passport. Then you an leave even if you have ECR.

Comment: _"while you try to board the flight"_ -- do Indian airports have exit controls located _at the gates_ -- if not, how would an immigration officer know where the traveler is going? And what if the _Republikflüchter_ flies to a non-banned country and transits there?

Comment: @Henning after checkin at airline counter, you pass through immigration control for international flights, there they ask you to show boarding pass, and even "may" ask visa. I flew to Kenya as visa-on-arrival, and it took calls to Kenyan Embassy and talking to Immigration Officer's senior to convince them that I do not need prior visa. And yes, lots of people fly to Dubai/Africa as tourist, and then to Banned Countries to circumvent, but almost everybody sorts ECNR/POE, costs about one day and 10/15 USD through touts.

Comment: @RedBaron yes, we both are right, when you have 10th certificate, or any other from the list, you can get ECNR. If you have no document from the list, then you need to get POE sticker.